# Можно ли скомпилировать файл .java без зависимостей?

Tags: java, android, декомпиляция, reverse-engineering

Есть ли возможность скомпилировать файл .java, не имея нужных зависимостей (по дефолту компилятор ругается)? А .smali?

Теоретически-то вполне возможно. Файл .class все равно ничего не знает о классах, методах и т.д., от которых зависит, в нем просто ссылки на них. Мы же можем создать html-страницу с гипер-ссылками, ведущими в 404, и IDE не помешают нам ее сохранить, и браузеры ее будут рендерить, а проблемы будут только при попытке перейти по ссылке. И никому не кажется это нелогичным.

Все это нужно для того, чтобы быстро подправить код декомпилированного/дизассемблированного приложения, "сохранить" обратно, и протестировать. Не тратя лишнее время на заморочки с другими модулями - да и на дизассемблирование их из class в smali.

Comment: Я думаю Ваш вопрос можно опубликовать как ответ)

Comment: Теоретически-то вполне возможно. Думаю, не нужно объяснять, почему. (c)

Comment: ...Или всё-таки нужно? Судя по странной реакции на вопрос. Как будто я спрашиваю "есть ли возможность убрать стандартное окно О програме из винды, где копирайт Microsoft". Ну хорошо, объясню. Файл .class все равно ничего не знает о классах, методах и т.д., от которых зависит, в нем просто ссылки на них. Мы же можем создать html-страницу с гипер-ссылками, ведущими в 404, и IDE не помешают нам ее сохранить, и браузеры ее будут рендерить, а проблемы будут только при попытке перейти по ссылке. И никому не кажется это нелогичным. А тут - на тебе.

Comment: Вот эти рассуждения надо бы добавить в сам вопрос, а не держать в комментариях :)

Comment: @D-side а смысл их добавлять? Они же даже не знают, для чего мне это нужно. Действуют по какому-то шаблону, вот вбили себе: то плохо, сё плохо,  и всё тут. Короче - бред и весеннее обострение. Думаю, не нужно объяснять, почему.))

Comment: @АндроидАндроид Про "теоретически" - это я для того, чтобы мне не писали, якобы невозможно в принципе. А то часто люди путают "нельзя" и "невозможно". А что нельзя - это уже индивидуально. Вот и выходит, что всё невозможно, чего они не хотят. Пусть лучше молча минусуют. А мне ПРАКТИЧЕСКОЕ решение нужно, если кто не понял. Типа какую настройку у компилятора включить. Или у ассемблера (для smali).

Comment: Вот за этот настрой "не нужно объяснять, почему" вас и минусуют. Потому что это нужно только в **совсем** экзотических случаях, и для вашей решаемой проблемы может быть решение гораздо проще. Есть известная XY-проблема: когда вопрос не о проблеме, а об ошибочной попытке решения проблемы. Объясните, почему вы хотите сделать именно так.

Comment: Ну и ["Пожалуйста, переносите всё важное из комментариев в вопрос и ответ"](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2408/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82) на Мете.

Comment: @D-side может быть мой случай для вас  и экзотический. ДЛЯ ВАС. Тогда что вы здесь делаете, если вы не реверс-инженер? Есть еще такая известная фраза: "каждое дело должен делать профессионал". А так, ничего экзотического нету, все это для того, чтобы быстро подправить код декомпилированного/дизассемблированного приложения, "сохранить" обратно, и протестировать. Не тратя лишнее время на заморочки с другими модулями - да и на дизассемблирование их из class в smali.

Comment: И это тоже добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: ваш вопрос минусуют только потому, что он плохого качества. Не придумывайте себе глупости вроде весеннего обострения. Просто отпадает желание помочь, когда видишь такой вопрос. Если вы хотите, чтобы вам помогли, утрудитесь написать чуть больше, чем 1 строку из 8 слов. И почему-то вы принимаете минусы к вашему вопросуна личный счет.

Comment: И, тем более, вы спросили ,есть ли возможность. И сами же ответили ,что она есть. Так в чем вопрос, собственно?

Comment: @D-side я добавил тэги - реверс-инжиниринг, дизассемблирование. Как я еще должен был объяснить, что вопрос по реверс-инжинирингу, а не штатной разработке? Вроде бы итак понятно. Второй тэг даже удалили - типа не нужен.

Comment: @metalurgus желание помочь? А возможность помочь у вас есть? Мне нужно знать, возможно ли такое сделать на практике и как. Вы знаете, как это сделать? А иначе смысла нет вопрос улучшать... Весеннее обострение - вовсе не выдумка, оно проявляется у многих или у всех, у кого-то сильнее, у кого-то слабее. Само его проявление - это либо просто физиология, либо карма и т.д., либо физиология через карму - как хочешь, так и трактуй, всяко это не в нашей власти. Но контролировать на что направить эмоции - мы можем и должны, и кто-то это делает, кто-то - нет.

Comment: @VZVZ как в комментариях.

Comment: Гугл говорит, что скомпилировать класс, не имея зависимостей нельзя. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728231/compile-java-code-without-dependencies Но я знаю способ обойти это: использовать рефлексию.

Comment: @metalurgus все обращения к зависимостям нужно сделать через рефлексию? Ну этот вариант и я знаю. Не этого я хотел. Думаю, не нужно объяснять, почему. Но, это про компиляцию java. А что насчет smali?

Answer (score 8):

Если не проверять зависимости при компиляции - будет неизвестна с точностью до типов параметров и возвращаемого значения сигнатура вызываемого метода.

А поскольку сигнатура вызываемого метода записывается в [пул констант класса](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4), невозможно будет сформировать итоговый `.class`-файл.

Comment: Хм... А что насчет компиляции не java, а smali? Казалось бы, получив .smali из .class, мы получили всю информацию, что в нем была. По логике ее должно бы быть достаточно, чтобы снова получить class.

Comment: По виду достаточно. Что мешает попробовать?

Comment: А зачем вообще вопросы задают? Ведь всё можно просто попробовать.

Comment: Вопросы обычно задают, когда попробовали, и что-то не получилось.

Comment: значит, надо еще попробовать. Попробовать иначе и т.д.

Comment: За эти три часа препирательств вы могли скачать backsmali и smali, разобрать и собрать какой-нибудь `.dex` и внести вклад в сообщество, опубликовав ответ на свой вопрос. Еще раз: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Все верно @Nofate сказал. smali/backsmali в руки и вперед. Влегкую можно собрать все, что нужно не имея зависимостей. С java так не выйдет.